# My three old questions got downvoted at the same moment

Tags: support

My three very old questions ( 9 month old or so ) on stackoverflow got suddenly down voted at the same time and I received a -6 reputation. When this happened, I was doing two things,

1. Rejected a suggested edit on my answer
2. Answered a question ( Answer got accepted )

I doubt something fishy or random but believe that I didn't received down votes in fair since it happened for three questions at the same time.

Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: They'll most likely get the serial votes removed at the end of the day, although why not take the time now that you're looking at them to see if you can edit them at all to make them slightly better?